# Convert Emgu CV Image to jpeg 2000 then store to an byte array

Tags: c#, emgucv

I can save a jpeg 2000 image file by following

```
Image<Bgr, byte> img; img.Save("photo.jp2");
```

How can I convert Emgu CV Image to jpeg 2000 then store to an byte array

Answer (score 1):

The Image class in emguv has a Bitmap property (see: [Image(TColor, TDepth).Bitmap](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/792e25d7-4ae8-52c3-eadb-c05ee7b7919f.htm) in the emgucv documentation) and so if you want just a JPEG encoded byte array for the image you can do this:

```
Image<Bgr, byte> img;

//...

byte[] bytes;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    img.Bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```